# discord bot doesn't respond

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a discord bot right now.
After a few errors it seems like it works.
The Bot is online, no errors shown but he doesn't respond to the command !image.
I gave the bot all permissions to send images, see the channel and upload files.
He's visible in the Channel & is online after i start the script.

I want that the bot post a random picture.

```
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import random,discord,os


load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('TOKEN')                                      #Load discord token from env file

help_command = commands.DefaultHelpCommand(                     # Change the no category to commands
    no_category = 'Commands'
)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', help_command=help_command)
client = discord.Client()

@bot.command(name='image', help='Send random image to chat')    #Command name and help for it
async def images(ctx):
    script_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))     #Get script directory
    filenames = os.listdir(script_dir + "/images")              #Get all files from images directory
    extensions = ['.png','.jpg','.gif']                         #Allowed file extensions
    images = []

    for i in filenames:                                         #Check if files have supported extensions
        if i.endswith(tuple(extensions)) and i not in images:
            images.append(i)

    random_img = script_dir + "/images/" + random.choice(images)     #Choose random image and add path to it
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File(random_img))                      #Send random image



bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Any errors reported in the command line?

Comment: No errors reported